# howto write rviz display plugin?

Tags: rviz, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
can someone explain me or show me a tutorial, how i can write a simple rviz plugin ?

i know http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html but thats not for catkin or indigo.

What do i learn, or what should i do, after install ros-indigo-rviz-plugin-tutorials ?

flo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206577/howto-write-rviz-display-plugin?/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2015-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can still install the visualization tutorials for indigo even though it says for hydro.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-visualization-tutorials
```

And if you want to use catkin, then just build with catkin instead via `catkin_make`

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2015-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0